# Microsoft C++ Optimizing Compiler crashing constantly

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mlpack

I am trying to build MLPack 0.8, and be it Release or Debug, my C++ Optimizing Compiler is constantly crashing. I have tried closing every other software to provide maximum RAM to the compiler, but that did not help.

My setup:

```
VS2010
Windows 7 x64
MLPack 0.8
Boost 1.55
Armadillo 4.320
LibIconv (latest version)
```

The solution was created by CMake 2.8.8

What can I do to compile the MLPack properly with my system, or anyone an idea where I could find already compiled libraries?

Edit: The log messages from services (in German, but you should get the idea what it says)

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: CL.exe, Version: 16.0.40219.1, Zeitstempel: 0x4d5f0c67
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: c1xx.dll, Version: 16.0.40219.1, Zeitstempel: 0x4d5f0cf9
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x000ca1e0
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x1cf0
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01cfa1c6ab273d06
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\c1xx.dll
Berichtskennung: edcfb3cd-0db9-11e4-8e71-f46d04884a75
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the compiler really crashing, or just throwing compile errors? What is the exact error message?

Comment: The CL.exe fails, so yes, its actually the compiler crashing. I have edited the error log into the original question.

Comment: Do you have the VS2010 Service Pack 1 installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. I will try later on my main machine with 16 GB RAM, maybe thats the issue. The compiler flips out with 3>g:\glukosescanner\mlpack-1.0.8\src\mlpack\core\tree\binary_space_tree\binary_space_tree_impl.hpp(683): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
3>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
3>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.     The line itself is Log::Assert(left == right + 1); so that looks odd enough

Comment: MS C++ compilers are not known for following the C++ standard properly. Your best bet is to use a far more recent version of MSVC (at least from 2012), or to use a proper and well tested C++ compiler such as GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is known to crash while compiling mlpack (or, more specifically, Armadillo).  Upgrading to VS2012 or newer should hopefully fix that issue; alternately, an older version of Armadillo may not stress the Visual Studio template subsystem too much.  As mtall noted, Visual Studio compilers are not known for their proper implementations of the C++ standards...

If you continue to have problems even after upgrading Visual Studio (if you are able to do so), make sure that you are using the most recently released version of mlpack (1.0.10, not 1.0.8 which is what I think you are using).

Comment: Yes, I updated to VS2012, now it works. Current Version is 1.0.10, but was 1.0.8 when I wrote the question.